# How were the swords made safe to humans?

Tags: movie, robots, westworld

In the film "Westworld" (1973) starring Yul Brynner, it's shown that the firearms in Westworld will not fire on humans because they contain a heat sensor, allowing the gun to fire if pointed at a cold object (an android) but not if pointed at a warm one (a human being). But in the other two "worlds", Romanworld and Mediaevalworld, where people are fighting with swords, how could they stage a realistic fight while ensuring that any human guest would not be harmed?

Comment: Because the robots are designed not to hit you with their swords. Obviously you can still hit yourself

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/Westworld -- ***BEWARE:*** link to TVTropes!

Comment: Though the question asked *realistic fight*, so if an opponent kept missing me I'd start to think "too easy".

Comment: @jim: Unless, of course, it default to flynning. Sometimes they miss, sometimes they hit your sword.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to make the swords brittle so they'll break if a dangerous level of force is applied.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the fight sequence between the "king" and the Black Knight robot, just before the Knight malfunctions we get a pretty good overview of the fight techniques used to make the guests feel that they're getting a good show, without actually being in any way dangerous:

- The knight will **only** attack when the opponent has both a shield and a sword.
- The knight repeatedly hits his opponent's shield, despite there being obvious openings.
- The knight repeatedly hits his opponent's sword, despite there being obvious openings.
- The knight repeatedly hits scenery items, despite there being obvious openings.
- The knight repeatedly misses his target entirely, despite there being obvious openings.

[image: A robot knight swinging a sword that hits the centre of a shield]

[image: A robot knight swinging a sword that widely misses its target]

[image: A robot knight swinging a sword that hits a candle holder, despite a person being in range of attack]

Since the robots have reflexes that are much better than humans, it can be expected that even if a human puts itself into harm's way during a fight, the robot would have the ability to trip, stumble or swerve their blade in such a way that makes a miss look organic.